# Finding a substring and extracting those lines from a text file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a  tab seperated text file which as a following format

```
Name      city            info
Stef     NY=123         ID=1;CITY=NY
John    SE=981;819      ID=110;CITY=SE
Stef      SE=01         ID=20;CITY=SE
Kelly   SE=111;787      ID=100;CITY=NY
Lena    NY=815;981;1    ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

I want to extract lines into a new text file where ID in third column is greater than 100 so the expected output becomes:

```
Name      city            info
John    SE=981;819     ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena    NY=815;981,1   ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

The awk command I have thus far is:

```
awk '$3 !~ /^ID=[0-9];/' file.txt > output.txt
```

However, this would only remove those lines where ID is 9 or less. I am not sure how to exclude all those lines where ID is less than 100. How can I achieve that. Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a really naive solution could be :

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    o=$3
    sub(/ID=/,"",o)
    if(o + 0 > 100) print
}' test
```

---

A more advanced approach could be :

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR == 1 || (match($3, /[0-9]+/) && substr($3, RSTART, RLENGTH) + 0 > 100)' test
```

Try to `match` for numbert of at least 3 digit in the third field.

`match` will set for us the variable `RLENGTH` at the index where the regexp start to match, or at 0 if no match is found at all.

Then we could check if the entire match (from `RSTART` to `RLENGTH`) is greather then 100. If it is, print the entire line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your real input looks like the example you provided:

```
$ awk -F'[=;]' 'NR==1 || $(NF-2)>100' file
Name      city            info
John    SE=981;819      ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena    NY=815;981;1    ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Here's how setting FS to `[=;]` is telling awk to split each record into fields:

```
$ awk -F'[=;]' '{print "---------" ORS $0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NF, i, "<"$i ">"}' file
---------
Name    city    info
1 1 <Name       city    info>
---------
Stef    NY=123  ID=1;CITY=NY
5 1 <Stef       NY>
5 2 <123        ID>
5 3 <1>
5 4 <CITY>
5 5 <NY>
---------
John    SE=981;819      ID=110;CITY=SE
6 1 <John       SE>
6 2 <981>
6 3 <819        ID>
6 4 <110>
6 5 <CITY>
6 6 <SE>
---------
Stef    SE=01   ID=20;CITY=SE
5 1 <Stef       SE>
5 2 <01 ID>
5 3 <20>
5 4 <CITY>
5 5 <SE>
---------
Kelly   SE=111;787      ID=100;CITY=NY
6 1 <Kelly      SE>
6 2 <111>
6 3 <787        ID>
6 4 <100>
6 5 <CITY>
6 6 <NY>
---------
Lena    NY=815;981;1    ID=2111;CITY=NY
7 1 <Lena       NY>
7 2 <815>
7 3 <981>
7 4 <1  ID>
7 5 <2111>
7 6 <CITY>
7 7 <NY>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My first two fields can have = or ; in them which is why I said $3 in my awk command. Could you modify your solution so that it takes that into account? Thank you

Comment: Many times people provide information in questions that they consider relevant but actually isn't (and vice-versa) which is why it's important to provide sample input that looks like your real data. Yes, I can update my answer but I might end up with the wrong answer again if I don't know what your input really looks like (e.g. maybe your fields are actually within quotes or can contain blanks, or can have `ID=` in other fields too like `GUID=1234`, or anything else you haven't shown us so far, idk) so please edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: I've made edits to my original question.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer.

Comment: Can you explain what $(NF-2) does?

Comment: Sure but first look up what `NF` means in the awk man page (or in the gawk manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-examining-fields). I added a script to show how each record is being broken down into fields to help explain what's happening. After looking up NF in the man page and reading my updated answer let me know if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
$ mlr --tsv filter 'i = splitkv($info, "=", ";"); i["ID"] > 100' file.txt
Name    city    info
John    SE      ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena    NY      ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F '\t' 'NR==1 || match($3,/ID=([0-9]+)/,arr) && arr[1]+0 > 100' file.txt
Name    city    info
John    SE      ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena    NY      ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format is the same throughout the file below the header:

```
awk -F '=|;' 'NR==1; $2>100' location
```

That sets the delimeter as either `=` or `;`, prints the header, and then, any lines after the first where the second field is greater than 100.

Output:

```
Name      city      info
John       SE     ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena       NY     ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Comment: What if I have = and ; in other two columns too. How would you modify it then?

Comment: @John You'll need to edit the column that's printed and/or change what the delimiter(s) is. If you'll look over `awk` via the man page and Google, that'll give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Split twice:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print; next } { split($3, array, /[=;]/); if(array[2]>100){ print} }' file
```

Output:

```
Name    city    info
John    SE      ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena    NY      ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
awk 'NR==1 || /ID=[0-9][0-9][0-9]+/ && !/ID=100/' file
Name      city      info
John       SE     ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena       NY     ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('file.txt','r')
spa=re.compile(r'\s+')
print k.readline().strip()
for li in k:
    remspa=re.sub(spa," ",li)
    numb=remspa.strip().split(' ')[2].split(';')[0].strip().split('=')[1].strip()
    if (int(numb) > 100):
        print li.strip()
```

output

```
Name      city      info
John       SE     ID=110;CITY=SE
Lena       NY     ID=2111;CITY=NY
```

Comment: You know `split()` would split the string correctly, without the need for that regular expression and `sub()`, right?